# in vim shift+w (W) does not work. It moves forward like w. How do I fix it?

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using vim 7.3, installed through homebrew on OS X 10.8.3. For some reason neither `W` or `E` works as expected in normal mode. Rather than moving backward one word at a time, it moves forward. The behavior of `W` is identical to `w`. And the behavior of `E` is identical to `e`.

I have tried the `o` and `O` command in normal mode and it works as expected, so it is not like my shift key is broken.

This is driving me nuts because it is such core functionality that I can't get to work. I have tried erasing my vimrc and vim directory and change shell.

I will okay the answer of anybody who can either solve the problem for me or give good advice on how to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. When in doubt, read the relevant part of `:help`… `:help b`, `:help B`, `:help e`, `:help E`, etc.

Comment: For future references; you don't need to delete your Vimrc for testing if there's something wrong in it; just do `$ vim -u NONE -U NONE`. See `$ man vim` for more information. Additionally, there could be something wrong in `~/.viminfo`, but that's just for those really weird behavioural bugs.

Comment: @timss Please stop adding `<kbd>` tags where they don't apply! Is there an `e` and an `E` key on your keyboard? Is there an `o` and an `O` key on your keyboard? I guess not. [This is how you use `<kbd>` tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156177).

Comment: I'll add that it's helpful to think of shifted letters as being either the [directional] reverse of their counterparts or as their superlatives. Reversals include: t/T, f/F, o/O, p/P, x/X, n/N. Superlatives include: w/W, e/E, b/B, ge/gE, r/R, y/Y, i/I, a/A, s/S, c/C, d/D, v/V, and even - accidentally - h/H and l/L.

Comment: @glts Fair enough. I find it confusing to know when to use it or not because it's both a keycombination, but also not actual keypresses. Is backticks for `W` better than <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>? If it's just lower case, is <kbd> better? And so forth. Either way, I'll try to be a little more conservative and stick with backticks.

Comment: @timss Vim has its own [notation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#notation) and this notation has been in use for the past 20+ years. Any Vim user needs to know this notation because it applies to mappings, :help, and popular literature such as *Practical Vim*. `<kbd>` tags are a nice little HTML feature but often they are more confusing than helpful to actual Vim users.

Comment: @glts That's a very good point. Thank you for pointing out my annoying usage of <kbd>, I didn't see big arguments against it before now, and my edits kept getting accepted so I didn't think much of it.

Comment: @timss Sorry, it's just a minor annoyance for me. Actually I learnt about `<kbd>` tags on Stackoverflow myself and I find them helpful (rarely), but Vim really requires its own precise notation because every key stroke counts! Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`W` and `E` are not the backward-versions of `w` and `e` (`b` and `ge` are, respectively).

Lowercase versions consider words to stop at non-word characters such as punctuation or whitespace. Uppercase versions only consider whitespace (therefore moving past words with punctuation in them). The vim manual explains all combinations clearly:

```
           ge      b          w                             e
           <-     <-         --->                          --->
    This is-a line, with special/separated/words (and some more).
       <----- <-----         -------------------->         ----->
         gE      B                   W                       E
```

You can find this overview in Getting Started under Moving Around (`:help usr_03.txt`), and more details at `:help word-motions`.

Comment: Good answer, but when referring to the Vim manual, please show the command that is used as it isn't always easy to find it.

Answer (score 10):

shift+W does *not* usually work backwards. It moves forwards like w, just with a different definition of "word" (e.g. W will skip over "hello-world", w will end up at the hyphen).

Moving backwards is b.

Please use the vim help (`:h W` in this instance) before thinking something is broken.

Comment: ... And `B` for the backward equivalent of `W`, moving greedily to the next whitespace character backward.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I was so stupid. I have used vim a lot before, and misremembered how it was used.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you described is not standard Vim, but if you're used to it, try these mappings:

```
nnoremap W B
nnoremap E gE
```

Answer (score 0):

`w` means go forward to the start of a "word". In Vim, a "word" means:

- sequence of alphanumerical and underscore (regex: `\w+`), or
- sequence of other non-blank characters (regex: `[^\s\w]+`)

`W` means go forward to the start of a "WORD". In Vim, a "WORD" means:

- a sequence of non-blank character (regex: `\S+`)

This example:

```
:help usr_03.txt
```

- contains 7 words: "`:`", "`help`", "`usr`", "`_`", "`03`", "`.`", "`txt`"
- contains 2 WORDs: "`:help`", "`usr_03.txt`"

`e`, `E`, `b`, `B` works in a similar manner.

---

Not directly related to the question, but if you want to find what a key (or key combination) does, simply use

```
:h {key}
```

Note: casing matters.

Examples:

- `:h W`
- `:h w`
- `:h yy`
- `:h CTRL-W_T` or the shorthand `^W_T`